# Concatenating multiple CSV files based on column values,but the multiple csv files have the same header but vary in order

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I'm cleaning some data.I have data from multiple subjects for multiple subjects over multiple trails.

```
SubNo Trails Score 
1       1      4
1       2      4
1       3      8
7       1      9
7       2      8
7       3      8
19
:
:
```

For the same subject, I have another dataset for indifferent  order for SubNo

```
SubNo Trails Height 
19      1      100
19      2      400
19      3      810
7       1      911
7       2      811
7       3      811
20      1      222
20      2      222
20      3      789
1
1
:
:
```

I want to join these two on SubNo, such that in the end I have one CSV per subject for both score and height.

```
SubNo Trails Score Height 
1        1     4     198
1        2     4     209
1        3     8     289
2        1     :      :
2        2
2        3
```

Here, I have joined the same data based on subNo: So,all the values of 1 together,all values of subject 2 together and so on.In my two csv files the order of subject is not the same.
So,I don't want to join based on header,but based on specific subject number.In my case ,that is 1,2,17,...like that.
How should I go about it? (I tried pandas merge,it works based on header).That's won't do what I want.

Comment: See `pd.merge()`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html and learn how to use it with `left_on`, `right_on` parameters.

Comment: Hi,I did try that out.The problem is that the order of SubNu in both these csv files are not the same.So the left on and right on doesn't work.@mac13k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey,so the solution I found was to sort each csv file on subnum and concatenate.

```
df1.sort_values(by=['Subnum','Trials'], ascending=True)
df2..sort_values(by=['Subnum','Trials'], ascending=True)
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but from what I undestand you are trying to get a single csv file which contains columns for SubNo, Trails, Score and Height (with SubNo column being the key)

in that case you should do following:

```
new_dataframe = left_dataframe.join(right_dataframe.set_index('SubNo'), on='SubNo', how='left')
```

or alternatively:

```
new_dataframe = pd.merge(left_dataframe, right_dataframe, on='SubNo', how='left')
```

Comment: ,I did try that out.The problem is that the order of SubNu in both these csv files are not the same.So the left on and right on doesn't work

Comment: in that case 'SubNo' cannot be used as a key, you could try using 'trails' column as key

Comment: Trials is 1,2,3.That won't help to merge subjects with same subject num.Or could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out pandas `merge` function. You will effectively be merging on `SubNo` and `Trials`. A small code snippet would be:

`df1.merge(df2, how='inner')`

After this step, you can perhaps slice by Subjects by using `groupby()` function (can be found in pandas documentation), by grouping the rows based on your SubNO and then save each group as a separate CSV

Comment: I did try that out.The problem is that the order of SubNu in both these files are not the same ORDER.So the left on and right on doesn't work

Comment: As far as I know, the order does not matter. Could you please edit your example to be a little more detailed on how it is not working, a sample output and expected output would help

Comment: just did that! Pandas merge works based on header values.What I want to do is within column values

Answer (score 0):

Use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['SubNo','Trails'],  how='left'))
```

---

```
SubNo  Trails  Score  Height
1       1      4      100
1       2      4      200
7       1      9      300
```

Comment: `/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys(self)
   1144                     inferred_right in string_types and inferred_left not in string_types
   1145                 ):
-> 1146                     raise ValueError(msg)
   1147 
   1148             # datetimelikes must match exactly

ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
'''